# Does Windows 8 UEFI Trusted Boot protect SSDT table from modification?

Tags: rootkits, windows-8, boot, uefi, driver

I read from a link that says:

> Trusted Boot takes over where Secure Boot leaves off. The bootloader verifies the digital signature of the Windows 8
>   kernel before loading it. The Windows 8 kernel, in turn, **verifies every other component of the Windows startup process,
>   including the boot drivers, startup files**, and ELAM.

My question: Is SSDT included in "every other component of the Windows startup process"?

Comment: PatchGuard is the component that protects SSDT and it's available on all versions of Windows using 64bit.

Comment: Googling for "SSDT hooking patchguard" will get you plenty.

edit: Apparently 'enter' sends a message.

http://uninformed.org/?v=3&a=3&t=pdf 

Ctrl + F SSDT. Second instance.